# Want to add cross icon or close button in modal/popup body to close the modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

Here this is my code:-

```
<button type="button" class="popupvideo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></button>

<!-- The Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" >
<!-- Modal body -->
  <button type="button"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></button>
  <a title="Close"><i ng-click="CloseModal()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon-arrow-right pull-right"></i></a>    
</div>
```

and i have added this also

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
```

but it is showing outside the Modal.

Comment: Your code is not visible.

Comment: To what element did you try to add your `<button>` element to (assuming this is your question)? Could you eloborate your question some more so that we might be able to help?